# Open XML file in AppleScript with JavaScript syntax

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing, applescript

I am writing my first bigger AppleScript and as I am usually developing TypeScript, I decided to use the JavaScript version of AppleScript. I need to read and parse an XML file.

Apple has an Example for that on their documentation, however the documentation only has an example in the AppleScript syntax, not in the JavaScript syntax:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/WorkwithXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH67-SW1

How do I actually do the given example in JavaScript?

I can read the file as a String, but that does not help me as I need to traverse the XML-tree.

Comment: Apple’s JavaScript for Automation is crippled and abandoned. Get Node.js.

Comment: I am actually using node.js for most stuff, and even developed this project in typescript which bundles and compiles to applescript. however I didn't figure out how to update playlists of apple music or rating of tracks using non-applescipt programming languages.

Comment: Yeah, Apple really screwed the pooch on supporting non-AppleScript languages: Scripting Bridge is garbage and JXA isn’t much better. (The Mac automation team finally got themselves disbanded/fired in 2016, for obvious reasons.) There’s Python/Ruby appscript, SwiftAutomation, and nodeautomation, which I wrote but no longer support. The Node bridge is non-functional due to bitrot in nodobjc; if you can fix that then you could use it, but generally I advise shelling out to osascript/calling AS handlers via ASOC as the least awful solution.

Comment: I am transmitting a lot of information (you can see the complete script down below) and think getting the information from osascript, then working with it and then putting it back to osascript. That would be around 1.000.000 calls to osascript. (Checking what Playlists exist, Updating the contents and updating all Song's BPM, Tonality etc.)

Comment: While commands can be performed on multiple objects for efficiency (e.g. `get name of every track…`, `get album of every track…`), if you’re setting lots of properties then, yeah, you’ll have to send a separate command for each one. TypeScript->JXA is probably your best choice if all you’re doing is getting and setting simple values. JXA works up to a point: it’s more complex operations like `move` and `duplicate` and record and enum types that tend to break. (The whole AppleScript stack went into maintenance mode after 2016, so you’re SOOL if you do run into one of those defects.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used webpack and an npm-package for parsing XML files to JSON: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-xml-parser

my code example is here:

https://github.com/kellertobias/rekordbox-to-music-playlists/blob/master/src/load-rekordbox.ts